# Comparing documents between two MongoDB collections

Tags: mongodb, join

I have two existing collections and need to populate a third collection based on the comparison between the two existing.

The two collections that need to be compared have the following schema:

```
// Settings collection:
{
  "Identifier":"ABC123",
  "C":"1",
  "U":"V",
  "Low":116,
  "High":124,
  "ImportLogId":1
}

// Data collection
{
  "Identifier":"ABC123",
  "C":"1",
  "U":"V",
  "Date":"11/6/2013 12AM",
  "Value":128,
  "ImportLogId": 1
}
```

I am new to MongoDB and NoSQL in general so I am having a tough time grasping how to do this. The SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT s.Identifier, r.ReadValue, r.U, r.C, r.Date
FROM Settings s
JOIN Reads r
  ON s.Identifier = r.Identifier
  AND s.C = r.C
  AND s.U = r.U
WHERE (r.Value <= s.Low OR r.Value >= s.High)
```

In this case using the sample data, I would want to return a record because the value from the Data collection is greater than the high value from the setting collection. Is this possible using Mongo queries or map reduce, or is this bad collection structure (i.e. maybe all of this should be in one collection)?

A few more additional notes:
The Settings collection should really only have 1 record per "Identifier". The Data collection will have many records per "Identifier". This process could potentially be scanning hundreds of thousands of documents at one time, so resource consideration is somewhat important

Comment: Why don't you use diff command ?

Comment: This is the type of thing that MongoDB really isn't designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good way of performing operation like this using MongoDB. If you want **BAD** way you can use code like this:

```
db.settings.find().forEach(
    function(doc) {
        data = db.data.find({
            Identifier: doc.Idendtifier,
            C: doc.C,
            U: doc.U,
            $or: [{Value: {$lte: doc.Low}}, {Value: {$gte: doc.High}}]
        }).toArray();
        // Do what you need
    }
)
```

but don't expect it will perform even remotely as good as any decent RDBMS.

You could rebuild your schema and embed documents from data collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("527a7f4b07c17a1f8ad009d2"),
    "Identifier" : "ABC123",
    "C" : "1",
    "U" : "V",
    "Low" : 116,
    "High" : 124,
    "ImportLogId" : 1,
    "Data" : [
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2013-11-06T00:00:00Z"),
            "Value" : 128
        },
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2013-10-09T00:00:00Z"),
            "Value" : 99
        }
    ]
}
```

It may work if number of embedded document is low but to be honest working with arrays of documents is far from being pleasant experience. Not even mention that you can easily hit document size limit with growing size of the Data array.

If this kind of operations is typical for your application I would consider using different solution. As much as I like MongoDB it works well only with certain type of data and access patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Without the concept of JOIN, you must change your approach and denormalize.

In your case, looks like you're doing a data log validation. My advice is looping settings collection and with each of them use the [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify) operator in order to set a validation flag on data collection records who matches; after that, you could just use the find operator on the data collection, filtering by the new flag.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, we can achieve this type of "join" with the new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) aggregation stage coupled with a classic `$group` stage:

```
// > db.settings.find()
//   { "Identifier" : "ABC123", "C" : "1", "U" : "V", "Low" : 116 }
//   { "Identifier" : "DEF456", "C" : "1", "U" : "W", "Low" : 416 }
//   { "Identifier" : "GHI789", "C" : "1", "U" : "W", "Low" : 142 }
// > db.data.find()
//   { "Identifier" : "ABC123", "C" : "1", "U" : "V", "Value" : 14 }
//   { "Identifier" : "GHI789", "C" : "1", "U" : "W", "Value" : 43 }
//   { "Identifier" : "ABC123", "C" : "1", "U" : "V", "Value" : 45 }
//   { "Identifier" : "DEF456", "C" : "1", "U" : "W", "Value" : 8  }
db.data.aggregate([
  { $unionWith: "settings" },
  { $group: {
      _id: { Identifier: "$Identifier", C: "$C", U: "$U" },
      Values: { $push: "$Value" },
      Low: { $mergeObjects: { v: "$Low" } }
  }},
  { $match: { "Low.v": { $lt: 150 } } },
  { $out: "result-collection" }
])
// > db.result-collection.find()
//   { _id: { Identifier: "ABC123", C: "1", U: "V" }, Values: [14, 45], Low: { v: 116 } }
//   { _id: { Identifier: "GHI789", C: "1", U: "W" }, Values: [43], Low: { v: 142 } }
```

This:

- Starts with a union of both collections into the pipeline via the new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) stage.
- Continues with a `$group` stage that:

  - Groups records based on `Identifier`, `C` and `U`
  - Accumulates `Value`s into an array
  - Accumulates `Low`s via a [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#mergeobjects-aggregation) operation in order to get a value of `Low` that isn't `null`. Using a `$first` wouldn't work since this could potentially take `null` first (for elements from the data collection). Whereas `$mergeObjects` discards `null` values when merging an object containing a non-null value.
- Then discards joined records whose `Low` value is bigger than let's say 150.
- And finally output resulting records to a third collection via an [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) stage.

Answer (score 0):

A feature we've developed called [Data Compare & Sync](https://cdn-web.studio3t.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/differences-tab-studio-3t-data-compare-sync.x75676.png) might be able to help here.

It lets you compare two MongoDB collections and see the differences (e.g. spot the same, missing, or different fields).

You can then export these comparison results to a CSV file, and use that to create your new, third collection.

[image: Export differences in two MongoDB collections to a CSV file]

***Disclosure**: We are the creators of the MongoDB GUI, Studio 3T.*

Comment: can we compare collections with different names?